# Example of each $\{f_n\}$ Riemann integrable such that $\sum f_n$ converges point-wise to $f$ which is not Riemann-integrable

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am looking for an example of a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of real valued Riemann integrable functions on a closed bounded interval such that $\sum f_n$ converges point-wise to a function $f$ which is not Riemann-integrable . Please help . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enumerate $\Bbb Q$ as $x_1, x_2, \dots$.  Then let $f_n(x_n)=1$, $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\not=x_n$.  Then $\sum f_n$ converges to the indicator function of $\Bbb Q$ which is not integrable.

Comment: the partial sums of $\sum f_n$ denote it by $s_n$ , satisfy : $s_n(x)=1 ,$ for $x \in \{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ , $s_n(x)=0$ otherwise . Does $s_n(x)$ converges pointwise to the dirichlet function ?

Comment: @SaunDev Yes $s_n$ converges pointwise to it.  In fact for any fixed $x\in\Bbb Q$, the sequence $s_n(x)$ is some number of zeros followed forever after by ones.  Such a sequence converges to one.  For $x\not\in\Bbb Q$ the sequence is all zeros.